# element.getAttribute is not a function

Tags: javascript

I would like to get the attributes of "element" into variables and I get the message "element.getAttribute is not a function" in the console.

What am I doing wrong here?

This is my full code :
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/rqrePo

The problem might come from initAudio(prev) and initAudio(next) but I am not sure where to look exactly.

When I click on previous and next, it is stopping at the first track because it is keeping the previous .active class (this class should be only on one track),
it is probably making conflict in the code.

Also think the part of the code with the issue is :

```js
let next = $('.player__list__track.active').next();
if (next.length == 0) {
   next = $('.player__list__track:first-child');
}
// Init Audio
function initAudio(element) {
  let song = element.getAttribute("song");
  const theSong = document.querySelector('.player__bottom__infos__song');
  theSong.textContent = songTitle;

  let imgCover = element.getAttribute("cover");
  let artistName = element.getAttribute("artist");

  // Create audio object
  audio = new Audio('media/' + song);

  // Infos
  artist.textContent = artistName;
  song.textContent = songTitle;

  // Cover
  //cover.setAttribute("src", "img/covers/" + imgCover);

  // Playlist
  track.classList.remove('active');
  element.classList.add('active');
}

// Previous
prevButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
  audio.pause();
  let prev = $('.player__list__track.active').prev();
  if (prev.length == 0) {
    prev = $('.player__list__track:last-child');
  }
  initAudio(prev);
  audio.play();
  songDuration();
});

// Next
nextButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
  audio.pause();
  let next = $('.player__list__track.active').next();
  if (next.length == 0) {
    next = $('.player__list__track:first-child');
  }
  initAudio(next);
  audio.play();
  songDuration();
});

const prevButton = document.querySelector('.player__bottom__controls__buttons__prev');
const nextButton = document.querySelector('.player__bottom__controls__buttons__next');

const artist = document.querySelector('.player__bottom__infos__artist');
const theSong = document.querySelector('.player__bottom__infos__song');
const cover = document.querySelector('.player__bottom__infos__cover');
```

```html
<!-- PLAYER LIST -->
<ul class="player__list">
  <li class="player__list__track" song="alan-walker-faded.mp3" cover="cover1.jpg" artist="Alan Walker" songtitle="Faded">Faded</li>
  <li class="player__list__track" song="avicii-levels.mp3" cover="cover2.jpg" artist="Avicii" songtitle="Levels">Levels</li>
  <li class="player__list__track" song="bastille-pompeii.mp3" cover="cover3.jpg" artist="Bastille" songtitle="Pompeii">Pompeii</li>
  <li class="player__list__track" song="imagine-dragons-radioactive.mp3" cover="cover4.jpg" artist="Imagine Dragons" songtitle="Radioactive">Radioactive</li>
  <li class="player__list__track" song="luis-fonsi-despacito.mp3" cover="cover5.jpg" artist="Luis Fonsi" songtitle="Despacito">Despacito</li>
  <li class="player__list__track" song="maroon5-animals.mp3" cover="cover6.jpg" artist="Maroon 5" songtitle="Animals">Animals</li>
  <li class="player__list__track" song="the-verve-bittersweet-symphony.mp3" cover="cover7.jpg" artist="The Verve" songtitle="Bittersweet Symphony">Bittersweet Symphony</li>
</ul>

<!-- PLAYER CONTENT -->
<div class="player__content">
  <div class="player__content__image">
    <img class="cover">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: x is probably undefined in `initAudio(x)`

Comment: You need to provide a [mcve] that actually reproduces the problem. You never call `initAudio` so the error you describe doesn't occur.

Comment: `cover.src = "img/covers/" + imgCover;` BTW what and where is `cover`?.

Comment: cover is the img tag, it should take the attribute cover from the li "the player__list__track"

Comment: You are right, cover was not defined (targeting the wrong class)

Answer (score 2):

You can show how get element?

Example (working):

```
var element = document.getElementsByTagName("li")[0].getAttribute("class");
```

Example (not working becouse is array):

```
var element = document.getElementsByTagName("li").getAttribute("class");
```

Comment: `let firstTrack = document.querySelector('.player__list__track').firstChild;
initAudio(firstTrack);`

Comment: @VincentWings: Please edit that into your question. (Also, the first child is probably a text node; try `.firstElementChild`, or `document.querySelector('.player__list__track *')`. Unless you were just trying to get the first `.player__list__track`, which is what `document.querySelector` already returns – remove `.firstChild` entirely in that case.)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, sorry... this is my first post.
Yes, it is true I don't need .firstChild but there is still the problem telling me element.getAttribute is not a function. 
element.getAttribute should get the attribute of the first track.

Comment: @VincentWings: When does your script run? i.e. what is the entire script and where is the `<script>` tag located in the HTML?

Comment: @Ry 
The script tag is just before the end of the body tag.
Please find my full code :
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/rqrePo

Comment: @VincentWings: Your Codepen doesn’t produce the error on startup. Is there some action in the UI that triggers it?

Comment: @Ry It happens when you click on a track in Chrome.

Comment: @VincentWings: Okay, so `initAudio(firstTrack)` isn’t relevant. It’s `initAudio(prev)` and `initAudio(next)` that matter. Please edit those into your question and try cutting everything else out of the Codepen (see [mcve]). `prev` and `next` are jQuery objects instead of DOM elements, and they don’t have `getAttribute`; `initAudio(prev.get(0))` and `initAudio(next.get(0))` should extract the DOM elements.

Comment: @Ry you are right,
I changed to initAudio(prev.get(0)) and initAudio(next.get(0)) and it worked! 
Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

I think this block is not working..
your next element is undefined. your list has no class name for getting active element.
You adding active element in initAudio method but its first line gets error for element is null.

```
// Init Audio
function initAudio(element) {
  let song = **element**.getAttribute("song");


 let next = $('.player__list__track.active').next();
  if (next.length == 0) {
    next = $('.player__list__track:first-child');
  }
```

Comment: When I click on previous and next, it is stopping at the first track because it is keeping the .active class